# Understanding derivation of rule that "פרו ורבו" is mandatory only for men?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, children-parenting, parashat-bereishit, masechet-yevamot

The Gmara (Yevamot 65b) says that the reason why men are the only ones that have to keep "פרו ורבו" is because right after it its written "וכבשוה" (the human has to take over the world), and men are the ones that do war. Since taking over and "פרו ורבו" are written together it is understood that men are the only ones that are obligated in them.

My problem is that the pasuk says "פרו ורבו" in a plural way and the only people that lived then by the Torah were Adam and Eve. This means that if Hashem would of want to tell this to only the men (then only Adam) he would of say "פרה ורבה"!?

Comment: I know the Sefer Hachinuch speaks about פרו ורבה (obviously). So you might want to take a look there. There's a chance he answers it or refers you to other sources that could answer it

Comment: Well on a peshat level it is probably not a mitzvah at all, but a blessing. If so, the whole interpretation is a derash that is not predicated on the text exclusively, so the whole question might not really start.

Comment: Note also that is is a machlocket Tannaim whether women are obligated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in [mitzvot habait page 83](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3412&st=&pgnum=82)

That it is because it was before the pain of child birth (also for the woman)

But after the pain it is in singular only the man has the (full) obligation

[Beraishis 35.11](http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8230#v=11)

> פְּרֵה וּרְבֵה

Comment: Thanks!
by the way who book is  mitzvot habait?

Comment: Thank you See http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3412&st=&pgnum=471&hilite= and http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3412&st=&pgnum=470&hilite=

Comment: I was told about it here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71488/5120

Answer (score 2):

If he would of say "פרה ורבה"

I would understand that only adom but not his children so it said in plural form to inclined the next generations

---

And the command is to do something active in Judaism the woman is not really doing something active

Comment: Interesting idea. Is it your own?

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, my humble opinion, (but I do not argue with the possibility that I heard this before and it was in my subconscious)

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you I am happy that you like it