# Books on Dating and Marriage

Tags: jewish-books, marriage, shidduchim-dating

Which books on the halakha and minhagim of dating and marriage are generally considered the most reliable?

Comment: I think Amazon displays popularity rankings.

Comment: this one has 4.5 stars https://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Way-Love-Marriage/dp/0824604806

Comment: Maimonides' _Ishut_ has been wildly popular over the years, I believe, though he focuses more on marriage than dating I suppose.

Comment: Is this really necessary? I know everybody thinks it's funny to make fun of poorly-worded questions, but it seems pretty obvious to me that the OP is asking for a product recommendation. If the downvotes are only because the question said "most popular" instead of something else, that's a real shame. Asking questions here should be incentivised. I've edited the question - if the OP wants to revert, s/he can change it back.

Comment: @ShimonbM While I agree that it is in poor taste to sarcastically comment on poorly worded question; even those from a user who posts large numbers of poor posts, in spite of constant criticism, I am not  sure that you are correct in your understanding of the question. Personally I suspected that the question was asking for a book filled with wise adages and good advice; not technical laws and customs.

Comment: Nor do I assume that by 'most popular', the OP meant 'most reliable'. @ShimonbM. Accordingly, this question is in dire need of clarification by the OP.

Comment: @RealTorah could you please [edit] this question to make it more objectively answerable? What kinds of books are you looking for: Modern? Classical? English? Hebrew?Academic? Popular? What criteria would make a particular choice ideal? Clearly-written? Authoritative? Comprehensive? Widely-used? etc.

Comment: @ShimonbM, I didn't think the OP meant what your edit said: I thought he/she meant to ask for the most popular. And I wasn't being sarcastic: I was pointing out an easy way the OP to find an answer to the question, and alluding to the fact that it's a poor question in that it's so easily researchable.

Answer (score 0):

Dating: is not halochikly obligated, or an official minhag (which a Rov wrote about in a book), so I guess there should not be any books , (unless the book is giving the logic and advice (and not the "halakha and minhagim") of how to do it)

Marriage: This book ([was recommended to me and](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71488)) it seems a **perfect** (but not in English) collection of minhagim and halochos of marriage, (not so much regarding marital relations) it is unusual becouse most books written even by Rabbis are heavily effected by phycology, and it is very very hard to seperate advice and the halocho/minhag.
[מצוות הבית](http://hebrewbooks.org/3412)

Another one but it is mostly regarding marital relations
[טהרת ישראל](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8159&pgnum=212)
On orach Chaim siman 240

---

There also is a collection of minhagin for shiduchim and the wedding here  (by nitoi gavriel)

http://hebrewbooks.org/46551
http://hebrewbooks.org/46545
http://hebrewbooks.org/46546