# If the Torah tells us to love the stranger, וַאֲהַבְתֶּם, אֶת-הַגֵּר is there a command to love one's husband/wife?

Tags: marriage, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, love

If the Torah tells us to love the stranger, וַאֲהַבְתֶּם, אֶת-הַגֵּר is there a command to love one's husband/wife?

Comment: I see these as two separate commandments, as the answers seem to indicate. Starting your question with "If" applies a causal relationship, which I don't think applies, here. Your wife is not a "stranger" - at least I hope, not!

Answer (score 5):

ואהבת לרעך כמוך includes loving ones wife. (See Rabbi Samson Refael Hirsh on the Pasuk). There reason a convert is written separately is people may not include a convert in ואהבת לרעך כמוך.

Comment: If the Torah tells us וַאֲהַבְתֶּם, אֶת-הַגֵּר , then is there a command to a wife to love her husband?

Comment: @ninamag: I would think that ואהבת לרעך כמוך includes loving ones husband also.

Comment: @Gershon_Gold I would think so, too, but I would like to know if any of our sages said the same thing.

Comment: @Gershon_God please teach me how one would point רע (of לרעך) in the feminine and in the masculine? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The Gemara in Kiddushin ([beginning of the 2nd chapter](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00899.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L5)) takes it for granted that the Mitzva of *וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ - love your friend as yourself* refers to one's spouse, which is why it is forbidden to marry somebody before seeing them.

> אסור לאדם שיקדש את האשה עד שיראנה שמא יראה בה דבר מגונה ותתגנה עליו ורחמנא אמר ואהבת לרעך כמוך

Comment: +1 Is it not sposificly the male seeing the female?

Comment: Consider one of the *Sheva Brachot's* phrasing - . שמח תשמח רעים האהובים - the term is referring to husband and wife.

Comment: @Danny-Schoemann is רֵעֲ (of לְרֵעֲךָ) pointed in the feminine? If yes, how does one point it in the masculine? (I ask this grammar-related question regardless if your answer is, it does not matter if it is in the masculine or feminine.)

Comment: @ninamag - Hebrew grammar is not my forté, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

BTW there is a Rabbinic commandment to love ones wife as oneself (some people explain that it means not more then oneself(since there already is a commandment to love all Jews))

It is brought in the Rambam [ishut 15](http://www.chabad.org/952889/):19

> **Similarly, our Sages commanded that a man** honor his wife more than his own person, and **love her as he loves his own person**....

The Rambam's source (acording to magid Mishnah)
Talmud Yevamot [62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b.19)

---

PS.
About love Rambam [De'ot 6](http://www.chabad.org/910346/)
 Halachah 3

> Each man is commanded to love each and every one of Israel as himself as [Leviticus 19:18] states: "Love your neighbor as yourself."
>   Therefore, one should speak the praises of [others] and show concern for their money just as he is concerned with his own money and seeks his own honor.
>   ...

Halachah 4

> Loving a convert who has come to nestle under the wings of the Shechinah [fulfills] two positive commandments: one for he is [also] included among the "neighbors" [whom we are commanded to love] and one because he is a convert and the Torah (Deuteronomy 10:19) states: "and you shall love the converts.".
>   [Thus, God] has commanded us concerning the love of a convert just as He has commanded us concerning loving Himself as [Deuteronomy 11:1] states: "and you shall love God, your Lord." The Holy One, blessed be He, Himself, loves converts as [Deuteronomy 10:18] states: "and He loves converts."

Chinuch [mitzva 431](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.431) love a ger.
[Mitzva 243](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.243) love a jew

Comment: If the Torah tells us וַאֲהַבְתֶּם, אֶת-הַגֵּר , then is there a command to a wife to love her husband?

Comment: @ninamag the command to love her husband is ואהבת לרעך כמוך your quote is not connected

Comment: @ninamag unless her husband is a ger

Comment: the command of veahahavto  lereacho comocho written in Kiddushin 41a is clearly deoraita and according to Hillel is the cornerstone of the entire torah

Comment: @user15464 I was referring to an additional commandment ,( I think the Rambam saw kidduchin 41a and still wrote what he wrote in ishus 15.19)

Comment: @user15464 and even in my answer I write "since there already is a commandment to love all Jews"

Comment: תנו רבנן האוהב את אשתו כגופו והמכבדה יותר מגופו עליו הכתוב אומר וידעת כי שלום אהלך ופקדת נוך ולא תחטא: Loving is min Hatorah which means having no resentment whatsoever and veahavto lireacho refers to your wife the most,there is no one else you spend as much time with .  being mechabed her means this מאכילו ומשקהו, מלביש ומכסה, מכניס ומוציא. ויתננו לו בסבר פנים יפות, שאפילו מאכילו בכל יום פטומות והראה לו פנים זועפות – נענש עליו.(sh ar yoreh dea 240) that is derabanan

Comment: @user15464 (I acknowledge that a man must love his wife becouse of a diorisa, i just see it as there is an additional dirabonon) your claim very interesting i would really like a source for your claim (I have been interested in this subject for years) see another point of view http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3412&st=&pgnum=304&hilite= from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71246/5120 , is your claim that always kavod means like by parents do you argue with the commentators on 240.24 (sposificly the pishai teshuva 240.20) http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6695

Comment: i read the page there is no argument on what i said, the definition of kovod always remains the same, you are only obligated with kovod min hatorah with your parents, however rabanan advise and  give a blessing to someone who gives kovod to his wife see my previous comment.

Comment: @user15464 that kovod means spending money , did you read piskai teshuva 240:20

Comment: Chinuch mitzvah 431, not 430. 430 is Bentching.